# Pass Strings getIntent to Listview in another Activity

Tags: android, adapter

I want to pass this code tokenizer to populate a listview in the next activity. Im using getintent() and custom adapter to next activity. Someone told me I should make custom adapter.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ClaimVoucherActivity.this,ClaimVoucherDetailsActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("customerID", customerID);
                        intent.putExtra("type", type);
                        intent.putExtra("name", name);
                        intent.putExtra("email", email);
                        intent.putExtra("voucher", voucher);
                        intent.putExtra("branch", branch);
                        intent.putExtra("issued", issued);
                        intent.putExtra("expiration", expiration);
                        intent.putExtra("status", status);
                        intent.putExtra("vouchername", vouchername);
                        intent.putExtra("employeeid", employeeid);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intent);
```

Here is the Custome Adapter

```
public class ClaimVoucherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ClaimVoucherActivity> {

private ArrayList<ClaimVoucherActivity> items;
private LayoutInflater vi;

TextView tvName,tvEmail,tvVoucherCode,tvIssueBranch,tvDateIssued,tvExpiration,tvStatus,tvVoucherSource;
public ClaimVoucherAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<ClaimVoucherActivity> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
        vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        ClaimVoucherActivity o = items.get(position);
        if (o != null) {

            tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            tvEmail = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
            tvVoucherCode = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvVoucherCode);
            tvIssueBranch = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvIssuingBranch);
            tvDateIssued = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvDateIssued);
            tvExpiration = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvExpirationDate);
            tvStatus = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);     
            tvVoucherSource = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvVoucherSource);


        }
        return v;
}
}
```

ClaimVoucherActivity.java

```
      Intent intent = this.getIntent();     
    String selected = intent.getStringExtra("customerID").trim();
    sType = intent.getStringExtra("type").trim();
    sName = intent.getStringExtra("name").trim();
    sEmail = intent.getStringExtra("email").trim();
    sVoucher = intent.getStringExtra("voucher").trim();
    sIssueBranch = intent.getStringExtra("branch").trim();
    sDateIssued = intent.getStringExtra("issued").trim();
    sExpiration = intent.getStringExtra("expiration").trim();
    sStatus = intent.getStringExtra("status").trim();
    sVoucherName = intent.getStringExtra("vouchername").trim();
    String employ = intent.getStringExtra("employeeid").trim();
        // Configure the listview

    ListView lstitems = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listView1);       
    setListAdapter(this.m_adapter);
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Any Issue or error??

Comment: The problem is I dont know how to do it.

Comment: Retrieve this all String in your next Activity and add it in List<String>

Comment: I added the custom adapter. Please check whats wrong

Comment: So how can I put the strings to listview using custom adapter?

Comment: You should simple retrieve your all data on onCreate() method and add that data to **ArrayList<ClaimVoucherActivity> items;** and pass this list to your adapter's constructor.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it base on my codes? I put it all.

Comment: ClaimVoucherActivity is a different class?

Comment: Yes. That's where I put the Listview.

Comment: Means is it ACtivity??

Comment: Yes the strings are from other activity and I want to pass it to another activity and show it using Listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add all data in List

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.add(selected);
myList.add(sType);
myList.add(sName);
myList.add(sEmail);
myList.add(sVoucher); //Add same for other which is remaining.
```

Now pass this list to your adapter

```
ClaimVoucherAdapter m_adapter = new ClaimVoucherAdapter(YourActivityName.this , R.layout.urlayoutName ,myList);
```

Now here

```
 public class ClaimVoucherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ClaimVoucherActivity> {

 private ArrayList<String> items;
 private LayoutInflater vi;

 TextView tvName,tvEmail,tvVoucherCode,tvIssueBranch,tvDateIssued,tvExpiration,tvStatus,tvVoucherSource;
 public ClaimVoucherAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,  ArrayList<String> items) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
    this.items = items;
    vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    //ClaimVoucherActivity o = items.get(position);
   // if (o != null) {

        tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        tvEmail = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
        tvVoucherCode = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvVoucherCode);
        tvIssueBranch = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvIssuingBranch);
        tvDateIssued = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvDateIssued);
        tvExpiration = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvExpirationDate);
        tvStatus = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);     
        tvVoucherSource = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvVoucherSource);

        tvEmail.setText(items.get(position).toString());
        // Now same do for all others Strings.
    //}
    return v;
}
}
```

Comment: But the datas/strings are from other activity. Thats why Im using getIntent()

Comment: I know that. you have just add your data in **ClaimVoucherDetailsActivity**

Comment: And the strings are returns from web. I dont put it manually. I added it in my code.

Comment: Okay, Im editing my code now. Please dont leave I need your help.

Comment: @jajaja You are going to be totally Confused... Just pass your data where you have parsed and according to my answer add it in your Activity.

Comment: I get error on ClaimVoucherAdapter m_adapter = new ClaimVoucherAdapter(YourActivityName.this , R.layout.urlayoutName ,myList);

Comment: **urlayoutName** is your layout name. SO you have written ur layout name

Comment: Yes I changed it. I get this error. The constructor ClaimVoucherAdapter(ClaimVoucherDetailsActivity, int, List<String>) is undefined

Comment: use this ClaimVoucherAdapter(ClaimVoucherDetailsActivity.this, int, List<String>)

Comment: where should I put that?

Comment: On onCreate() method after add all data in List

Comment: ClaimVoucherAdapter m_adapter = new ClaimVoucherAdapter(ClaimVoucherDetailsActivity.this , R.layout.list,myList);
  setListAdapter(m_adapter);

Comment: It says its undefined. Should I modify the adapter also? What should I put?

Comment: Change this public class ClaimVoucherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ClaimVoucherActivity> to public class ClaimVoucherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>

Comment: What error? Is your Class extends with Activiy or ListActivity??

Comment: it extends FragmentActivity

Comment: So change this from setListAdapter(this.m_adapter); to lstitems.setAdapter(m_adapter);

Comment: It's working now. But the problem is the it has multiple return from web. Do you know how to handle it?

Comment: You have to store it in HashMap Arraylist.

Comment: But How. I'm sorry. Can I know how to do it. :(

Comment: Can I use object list instead of hashmap?

Comment: How can I put it to the CustomeAdapter?

Answer (score 1):

You can get those data in next activity like this.

```
Intent i = getIntent();
customerID= i.getStringExtra("customerID");
type= i.getStringExtra("type");
name= i.getStringExtra("name");
...............
...............
```

Then create list and add data to list. after create adapter and set list to adapter.

add to list

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(customerID);
list.add(type);
..................
..........
```

Then add to adapter

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(YourActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

here list is your ListView

Comment: Im adding the strings from web